# Passing zero parameters to call_user_func_array

Tags: php, parameters, arguments, call

Consider the following situation:

```
call_user_func_array(array($this, 'method'), array());
```

This works fine, but I'm wondering whether this is the right way to pass **zero** parameters to the method. I've tried passing `null` instead of `array()`, but that gives me an error.

**Question:** what is the right way to pass zero arguments to the method called by `call_user_func_array`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [call_user_func](http://php.net/call_user_func). See an [example](http://codepad.org/vJOQYq1Q)

```
<?php
class MyClass
{

    public function callableFunc()
    {
        echo "Called" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function call()
    {
        echo "Calling callable from other function" . PHP_EOL;
        call_user_func(array($this, 'callableFunc'));
    }

}

$class = new MyClass;

call_user_func(array($class, 'callableFunc'));
$class->call();
```

Comment: What about object structures? I need to call a method of `this`.

Comment: @doitmyway you mean like this?